# Why do many garages only have 2-3 ceiling joists

Tags: framing, construction

I've noticed several garages now that only have 2-3 ceiling joists typically a 2x6 or 2x8. Why is that? I thought you would need joists spanning the whole length. It seems typical in older garages in my area. Are those three enough to support the weight of the roof from pushing out on the walls? Or is it because the pitch of a garage roof is much more shallow than a house? I've seen in both attached and detached garages

Answer (score 2):

All they are is rafter ties (not joists, not suitable for supporting either a ceiling or floor) to hold the walls together - the building is built as cheaply as possible to just barely stand up and hold roof loads, no more, unless the customer spent more before it was built.

Because they act in tension and the loads are transferred by the top plate, only a few are needed, and more than a few would be extra expense.

Comment: I suspect it may be regional as well. More needed (and/or other things to hold the roof together) in hurricane areas and in snow areas. In areas with neither frequent snow nor hurricanes, expect the bare minimum.